# camera.getPicture is lagging too much of time in cordova ios from select gallery

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I used cordova camera plugin for getting picture from the gallery in ios, for me the image gallery files not display faster its take too much of time to load...
i used below codes only. its working, but its takes too much of time to load Photolibrary and one more thing was savetoPhotoAlbum is not working.
But for android these two was work fine, its lag only on iOS

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
      quality: 30,     
      allowEdit : false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
```

Please help me anyone ...

Comment: I just build a new project with only the camera plugin and i have none of the issues you describe here. All is working fine and smooth the the mistake must be anywhere in your code.

Comment: I am also created a new project only with the camera plugin. Its still delays almost 20-30 sec to show the gallery popup. There are ~2K photos are in the device. is this the cause?

Comment: Could be the reason why it's lagging,... i have about 600 pictures and an delay from about 1sec. :-/

Comment: Is there anything we can do to reduce the delay in my case?

Comment: How did you get on with this @HariNarayanan? Did you find any way to make it faster?

Comment: yes @Jonny White use the below code for in css do this #file-input{
    display: none;
  } and in html do this <div>
 <label for="file-input" style="width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0px;">
 <input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />
 </div>   i am sure this will help you...   with out use of the camera plugin in iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important giving "mediaType" value like "mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE" in option.

```
  getImage(pictureSourceType, crop = true, quality = 50, allowEdit = true, saveToAlbum = true) {
    const options = {
      quality,
      allowEdit,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: pictureSourceType,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: saveToAlbum,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    };

    // If set to crop, restricts the image to a square of 600 by 600
    if (crop) {
      options['targetWidth'] = 600;
      options['targetHeight'] = 600;
    }

    return this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
      console.log("test 4");
      const base64Image = imageData;
      return base64Image;
    }, error => {
      console.log('CAMERA ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```